# Linking registered Microsoft app to xbox login

Tags: azure, xbox, xbox-live

I am working on a mobile app that will allow users to login to their xbox live account to access some xbox live account info and data (really only dvr clips and thumbnails). I registered my app in azure but can't figure out how to link it to the Xbox services. I'm not sure what scope to add or how to change it the xbox branding.

**Desired Link Screen**
(Currently I just have a regular Microsoft account login without xbox branding)

[image: d]

Comment: have you found the solution?